# how to delete item from nested array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**This is how my "Users" databse looks like**:

---

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1408d3c0e8c130503daafd"),
    "username" : "Akhil Jagga",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f15cde9329fc9300c7f3843"),
            "nameOfList" : "home",
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f15cde9329fc9300c7f3844"),
                    "nameOfItem" : "this is the list item"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f15cebd9a97051d80c6c6ad"),
            "nameOfList" : "personal",
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f15cebd9a97051d80c6c6ae"),
                    "nameOfItem" : "this is the list item"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f15cfd0d73dc330dc8e7fd1"),
                    "nameOfItem" : "lol"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 48
}
```

**I want to delete a specific object from "items" array say with ObjectId("5f15cebd9a97051d80c6c6ae"), using mongoose in nodejs .**

I tried by writting the following code but it does't work:

```js
app.post("/delete", redirectLogin, function(req, res) {
    const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
    const checkedItemName = req.body.hiddenInput;
    const listName = req.body.listName;
    console.log("item id: " + checkedItemId);
    
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            username: req.session.userId
        }, 
        {
            $pull: {
                data: {
                    items: {
                        _id: checkedItemId
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        function(err, foundList) {
            console.log(foundList);
            res.redirect("/");
        });
});
```

- I have tried using findOneAndUpdate, if I write name of item with the
  id it deletes the whole list from data array containing that item
  name and id.

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: What does this have to do with the [tag:r] programming language?

Comment: Hey new contributor, I would recommend you to be more specific in writing your questions, sometimes writing questions with details is the half answer you are seeking. from your questions, it is not possible to understand which specific item you want to remove. Try to provide more details of you question

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
const username = req.session.userId;
const listName = req.body.listName;
const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;

User.update({ "username": username}, { "$pull": { `data.${listName}.items`: { "_id": checkedItemId } }}, { safe: true, multi:true }, function(err, obj) {
//do rest
});
```

Comment: i have tried something related to this but this deletes the whole list instead of particular item in the list